# Bootstrap Carousel Javascript Override

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form that has one main field and a then bootstrap carousel that contains nested forms (there are multiple nested forms and the main form accepts nested attributes for these).  Everything is functioning properly but I would like to add a validation.  I'm using Jquery Validation http://jqueryvalidation.org/ for my other validations.

What I would like to do is have the bootstrap "next" button ONLY scroll next if the active form is filled out properly.  I am having trouble finding the Bootstrap javascript that I might have to override and also could use help conceptually on what the best way to go about this is.

So far I've thought,
1. add JQuery Validation to each individual form that way then the user gets to the new form it will message them if they do not fill it out properly (however I think they could still just hit next if they don't start typing in the form)
2. Add logic to the next button so that if the active form fields are filled it functions properly but if the fields are not filled then it triggers a message.

I'm leaning towards the latter but open to other ideas as well.  Before writing too much code, I would appreciate advice on how to override the javascript of the carousel next button and how to check for field completion but any other ways of going about this are definitely welcomed.

Thank you!

Comment: That sounds like a horrible abuse of the carousel widget.

Comment: I agree with @cvrebert. And your question does not really fit the format of this website.  Questions are expected to be concise and specific.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You "override" the next button by using one of the methods or callback functions provided by the plugin itself (did you check the docs?).  Otherwise, you'll find yourself modifying the plugin source, which by then, you might as well write your own code instead of using a plugin.

Comment: @cvrebert I am not too proud to admit that my carousel is feeling quite abused and I will most likely ditch it.  My carousel thanks you.